# 7 Trees, 6 Rows, 3 Per Row?

Tags: geometry

Can you arrange 7 trees so that there are 6 rows of 3 trees? It is entirely possible.

**Note: A tree can be part of more then one row, for example a if you arranged a 3x3 square (9 trees) the tree in the center is part of 4 rows.**

Rows are usually horizontal but in this case they can be horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: 7 trees - 6 lines]

(Joel Rondeau's solution would look like this:

```
    1
   2 3
    4
 5  6  7
```

With lines: 125, 137, 146, 247, 345, 567. A more symmetric solution than mine)

Comment: That's slightly off...

Comment: How? Please show how this solution is wrong? Could it be there are more solutions that you are not aware of?

Comment: Now it looks good. Your solution with numbers didn't line up properly.

Comment: @OleTange it was possibly a bit confusing because in the diagram you've drawn your cross section has been lined up correctly.

Answer (score 18):

An equilateral triangle with 3 trees at the corners, 3 trees at the midpoints and one tree in the center.

Each side has 3 trees. Each altitude has 3 trees.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a picture?

Comment: Picture added, seems a bit too late.

Answer (score 8):

this is my solution...

and this is done by **euler line** which i studied in high school.

[euler line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)

[image]

Comment: Tangentially related: the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane), the [Transylvanian lottery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transylvania_lottery) problem, and the board game [fire and ice](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4643/fire-and-ice) (played on a Fano plane of Fano planes).

Answer (score 1):

> North pole, south pole and 5 along the equator...10 rows :-)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE :) Congratulations on your very first answer but it is a bit too unclear. Perhaps giving a picture of your answer will be better. Nevertheless, I encourage you to write and answer puzzles in this site. Don't forget to visit the Help Center (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and check out other puzzles. Happy Puzzling :D

Comment: That's definitely an interesting answer, as it uses the third dimension (and the original question didn't specify the trees must be on a plane). What does confuse me is that with 5 trees on the equator, there are only 5 lines that join each equatorial tree with the poles (N. Pole -> Equator -> S.Pole), so I'm a bit lost as to how you get 10 lines, unless you've double counted something. One way around this would be to arrange 4 of the 5 equatorial trees such that you can make a straight line from Equator -> N. Pole -> Opposite Equator, and mirror it with the other pole, giving 9 lines in all.

Comment: there are 5 trees on the equator..1,2,3,4,5..so 123, 234, 345, 451 and 512 are 5 more lines..similarly 1NP2 is a line, 1NP3 is another, so is 1NP4..also 1SP2, and so on (any longitude is a straight line).. i think this will mean there are a total of 30 such lines

Comment: While clever, I'm not sure if spherical geometry is in the spirit of the answer

Comment: I know it's not in the spirit...but I did follow the letter, or rather the line of the puzzle :-) Sriram Sathyamoorthy