# Can you arrange 36 trees so that there are 9 rows of 8 trees?

Tags: geometry

How could you arrange 36 trees into 9 rows of 8? (Note that a row is a straight line that can go in *any* direction.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [7 Trees, 6 Rows, 3 Per Row?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/7-trees-6-rows-3-per-row)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate, just a similar class of problem

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I've edited your question to make it clearer what you mean - feel free to edit back if I've accidentally changed it away from your intended question!

Comment: Thanks Deusovi. Thats exactly what I mean in my question. And its not a duplicate dcfyj i tried. I hope i get an answer for that math problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Draw nine lines so that no two are parallel and no three meet in the same place, then place a tree at each intersection point. Every pair of lines intersects, so there are $\binom{9}{2}=36$ trees, each row being one of the nine lines.

Illustration:

> [image]