# How many Christmas Trees?

Tags: mathematics, situation, seasonal

*It's kinda late for this kind of joke, but I'm still going to go ahead and post it. :)*

```
An apartment owner told me to plant Christmas trees for him in the central plaza.

He told me to plant 7 rows of 6 Christmas trees each, and gave me $4200
dollars to buy the trees, and an extra $500 dollars for my help.

I bought the Christmas trees for $100 each and planted 7 rows of 6 Christmas trees.

I turned a profit of approximately 2500 bucks.

How did I do it?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your payment and the profit

> we can deduct that you bought $22$ trees. $21$ for the following structure:
>  [image]
>  And one for your own home.

Comment: This idea is taken from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49574/40914).