# An Amazing Configuration

Tags: mathematics, optimization, number-theory

Ed Pegg found in December 2019 this amazing configuration consisting of 22 points in 28 lines of 4.

On those points place 22 different positive integers such that the sum of any of the four points in a line is always the same.

¿How small can the largest of those numbers be?

[image]

Comment: This diagram reminds me of [A very old puzzle, #146 from American Agriculturist, April 1865](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116411/twenty-four-trees-in-eighteen-rows-of-four)

Comment: I wonder if rot13(Ibh xarj gur fbyhgvba naq vs Ibh unq n qussrerag yvar bs ernfbavat)?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a link to the first sentence, for the discovery by this Ed Pegg?

Comment: @Oliphaunt Check Ed's FB page. That was my source.

Comment: Source (page is in Chinese, so search for the first instance of "22" to find it): https://emathgroup.github.io/blog/orchard-planting-problem Very similar figure:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnbaum%E2%80%93Rigby_configuration

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos On Ed Pegg's FB page (in a comment to the relevant post) he says "I didn't find it. There's a chinese website devoted to the orchard problem, and the above was found after a multi-year search." I'm not sure what the right attribution would be, but apparently it doesn't originate with Ed himself.

Answer (score 20):

I think the answer is

> **It is impossible, no matter the upper bound.**

The solution is given by the image below:

> [image]
>
>  [Here](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/rr57ekzb) is the GeoGebra project that produced this image.
>
>  Consider the sums of five blue lines and five red lines. Other than the two points B1 on two blue lines and C1 on red, all points are counted in both sums the equal number of times. This proves that B1 = C1, which contradicts with the "distinct numbers" condition.

This was found by

> trascribing the conditions into [this Z3 script](https://tio.run/##fZZNj9NADIbv/RXDLRGqRL6lhb1x4cAFaO6xM4KKbbJKUmnFny/2JKSD65kerSeJ55nXVv8Ut1sy2@U4vi7ncTBPr9PYX9Eer8PcLUccJzubZbra9HBIeosv3WSpOsyL6TLzZVhSI8u5Xi70cqmXK71cu7KsNq4q@wO9P9D7A70/0PsDvT9Q@wO9P9T7Q70/1PtDvT/U@0O1P9T769VXzNeLWr90b@tbDkk3z3ZaTPLOJM@unn2gX2qehu5ie/O1e0sF9unZZJwngnfsW5cR9kjlgspVqhBUoVKloEqVqgRVqVQtqFqlGkE1qgoQKkBVAUIFqCpAqABVBQgVoKoAoQJUFSBUgKoChArQVaBQgaoKFCpQVYFCBaoqUKhAVQUKFaiqQKECVRUoVKCuov@f6iXUn@flPKDbzDQmNAMUcEovRZNyBy4wlAa6arpHuiS6AXTqyAsdmk5E7VIv/f6Nz@c5fZho3gDJe/7I@hqerX8P/JC3c8fz7ZM8ZDueB/GCWeDp8/AiiJfb@XjsdrwM4tXmgudvx6sgXm/eeCXteB3Em80x76Ydb4ImwaUJ@ak7fwqapM75nli/hwdNUuf0amT9Hh40SZ2jmxTw1JyCJumUHCDW7@FBkxQBDhvr9/CgSU5oyacFL2MnNpngL4u/j/QfJZLPNdp@4NpMPJv8pP8@9/864fCuM@KnsY2Fd50nP41tLLzr7PlpbGPhXefUT2MbCy@6QffT2MbCuy4Ff6zbJroG3Jbu7/j36BbI@e0@HV0CBZv36egOKFm8T0dXQMXefTq6AWrW7tPRBdCsm/ROrwq96H00LnyXsbcvj0G83f4C) and studying the "unsat core", i.e. a collection of conditions that leads to contradiction. Note that the unsat core does not involve any condition related to `max`.

---

@quarague asked about the case where some numbers can be equal but not all of them. In this case, the answer is

> **still impossible.**

> In the diagram, there are three regular heptagons that share the center. Let's call the vertices of the largest one $A_i$, the second largest $B_i$, and the smallest $C_i$, with $1 \le i \le 7$, and the center itself $D$. The vertices are numbered so that $A_i, B_i, C_i, D$ are collinear. Also, let's write the numbers written on each point in lowercase, i.e. $a_i, b_i, c_i, d$. The "solution" above contains an image with this way of labeling.

> In the picture above, I proved that $b_i = c_i$. Looking at the lines that pass through two $B$s and two $C$s, we get seven sums consisting of four $b_i$s. Two of them are $b_1 + b_2 + b_4 + b_5$ and $b_1 + b_2 + b_5 + b_6$ (from the two lines starting from $B_5$), which proves that $b_4 = b_6$. By rotational symmetry, we conclude that all $b_i$s and all $c_i$s are equal.

> Then we turn to the lines that pass through two $A$s and two $B$s. Since all $b_i$s are equal, we get equations like $a_1 + a_3 = a_3 + a_5$, which again proves that all $a_i$s are equal. Also, since $2a + 2b = 2b + 2c$, $a = c$. Finally any one line passing through $D$ proves that $d$ is also equal to the rest of the numbers.

Comment: Very nice. I wonder if there is any distribution of 22 not necessarily distinct integers on the points such that all 28 lines sum to the same apart from the trivial one where all integers are equal.

Comment: @quarague I addressed your bonus question as an edit.

Comment: @Bubbler Nice job! Does this also mean one cannot place 22 different numbers such that products are now equal?

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Yes. I believe the same proof works for nonzero numbers. If you have a zero somewhere, some products are zero while the others are not, which makes them not equal.